# Undo calendar event deletion

Tags: google-calendar

Is there any trash for deleted events on Google Calendar?

For some events, upon deletion there is no undo as shown below, so I'd be interested if there is any event thrash available.

[image]

Comment: [google apps support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1084819?hl=en) basically says "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Can I recover a deleted Calendar event? - Google Apps Administrator Help](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1084819?hl=en)

> > #### Short answer:
> >
> > Once an event is deleted, its full details can't be recovered. However, you may be able to retrieve some information about
> >     the deleted event by accessing your calendar through an XML feed.
>
> If you accidentally delete a calendar event, you have the following
>   options:
>
> - Quickly click the Undo link that appears above the calendar grid right after you delete the event. This Undo feature only appears for a
>     few moments or until you begin a new Calendar action.
> - If the window of time has passed where you can undo deleting your event, recreate it in Calendar.
> - If you have forgotten the event details, search your Inbox and Sent Mail to see if you sent an invitation about the event.
> - If you've tried these, and you still can't recover your event, and you need to recover the event or some details from it, there is a
>     complex workaround where you may be able to recover some of the event
>     details.
>
> Note: This is a complex workaround intended only for Google Apps
>   administrators and expert Google Apps users. If you accidentally
>   deleted an event, we recommend you just recreate it in Google
>   Calendar, instead of going through this process.

To read the complex workaround follow the link in the first line of this answer.